# SQL performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-performance

I have replaced my old processor with a [Xeon processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/75787/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2609-v2-10M-Cache-2_50-GHz) . I don't have hyper threading. My old processor had hyperthreading and was working fine.

I have SQL server 2012 standard edition installed. 
I have one single SQL server instance on the server, with 92GB of RAM.

Now after the change to the processor .I get a very high CPU and page Faults at 100% in the perfmon results.

1) Is Hyperthreading a key factor for performance

2) IS there any  check that I need to make sure that the SQL server is set to take advantage to mitigate these page faults.

3) Is there any DMV for wait statistics that I need to check the SQL performance
that will give some key insights.

4) Is there any best practices of SQL/ system performance counters that I need to evaluate.

The problem I have is perfmon is very resource intensive so cannot run it on the production server. are there any best practices to avoid these issues.

5) Is MAXDOP, processor affinity or I/O affinity worth changing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to explain this as per my knowledge and some googling.

**1) Is Hyperthreading a key factor for performance**

Hyperthreading is the SQL Server poster child for "it depends".
How hyperthreading will behave in your environment is dependent upon;

```
Your workload
Windows Server OS version
SQL Server Version
Physical CPU chip/chipset 
including cache size
```

Here are a few broad guidelines on hyperthreading;

Turn off hyperthreading if the logical CPU count that would result exceeds the number of CPUs supported by your OS or other software.  Example: Windows Server 2008 R2 supports up to 64 logical  processors, If you have a 40 core server (4, 10 core processors) hyperthreading would result in 80 logical cores. This is 16 cores greater than the OS will support. At start up those 16 logical cores will not be initialized and will be idle.  That is 8 physical cores of processing power not in use.

Turn off hyperthreading for SQL Server 2005 (in most cases). Some of the synchronization primitives do not see hyperthreading for what it is and interpret it as a multi core processor and some soft NUMA memory behaviours may occur that impact performance. This may be seen when processes execute that scan through large sections of memory. They may not affect your workload though so quantify your choice with testing.

Test hyperthreading with your workload for SQL Server 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012.  Hyperthreading is fully supported within the SQLOS without issue, but the nature of your specific workload may create issues related to I/O or read in-efficiency.  The results may be seen as excessive CXPACKET waits that are due to the timing of true CPU threads vs.hyperthreading CPU threads.   High CXPACKET waits may be observed even when MAXDOP is set to 1.

Some confusion:  As per Glenn Berry's S[QL Server Hardware book](https://www.simple-talk.com/books/sql-books/sql-server-hardware/) , "**as a general rule, Hyper-threading should be disabled for OLAP-style workloads, and enabled for OLTP-style workloads**, but as per Simple-talk Editor-in-chief "Tony Davis", [It is the wrong way round](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Editorial/72244/), surely, it is OLAP-style workloads, characterized by complex, long-running queries, which will benefit most from parallelization?

Well, yes and no, and it depends on exactly what you mean by parallelization. It's certainly true that, for an OLAP workload, query execution performance will benefit from allowing the query optimizer to 'parallelize' individual queries. This is the process where it 'breaks down' a query, spreads its execution across multiple CPUs and threads, and then re-assembles the result. For an ideal OLAP workload, it would be typical to leave the MAXDOP setting at its default value of zero (unbounded), allowing the optimizer to spread the query execution across as many cores as are available.

Unfortunately, it turns out that this only works well when you have a high number of true, physical cores (such as offered by some of the new AMD Magny Cours processors). Complex, long-running queries simply do not run well on logical cores, and so enabling HT tends to have a detrimental impact on performance.

msdn source : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqladventurer/archive/2012/07/11/hyperthreading-turbo-boost-sql-server-and-you.aspx

and another gud discussion here 
https://serverfault.com/questions/194377/will-disabling-hyperthreading-improve-performance-on-our-sql-server-install

**2) IS there any check that I need to make sure that the SQL server is set to take advantage to mitigate these page faults.**

To track paging, you can log counters: Memory\ Page Faults/sec, Memory\ Cache Faults/sec, and Memory\ Page Reads/sec. The first two of these track working sets and the File System Cache. The Page Reads counter helps you track hard page faults: a high rate of page faults coupled with a high rate of page reads (these also show up in the Disk counters) indicates a high rate of hard faults.

msdn source: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742410.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742467.aspx

**3) Is there any DMV for wait statistics that I need to check the SQL performance that will give some key insights.**

The sys.dm_os_wait_stats Dynamic Management View (DMV) can be used to identify any major resource waits in the system.
 More details: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/a-performance-troubleshooting-methodology-for-sql-server/

DBCC SQLPERF ('sys.dm_os_wait_stats', CLEAR);

4) Is there any best practices of SQL/ system performance counters that I need to evaluate.

```
Memory – Available MBytes
Paging File – % Usage
Physical Disk – Avg. Disk sec/Read
Physical Disk – Avg. Disk sec/Write
Physical Disk – Disk Reads/sec
Physical Disk – Disk Writes/sec
Processor – % Processor Time
SQLServer: Buffer Manager – Page life expectancy
SQLServer: General Statistics – User Connections
SQLServer: Memory Manager – Memory Grants Pending
SQLServer: SQL Statistics – Batch Requests/sec
SQLServer: SQL Statistics – Compilations/sec
SQLServer: SQL Statistics – Recompilations/sec
System – Processor Queue Length
```

5) Is MAXDOP, processor affinity or I/O affinity worth changing.
Yes,

Limitations and Restrictions

If the affinity mask option is not set to the default, it may restrict the number of processors available to SQL Server on symmetric multiprocessing (SMP) systems.

Recommendations

This option is an advanced option and should be changed only by an experienced database administrator or certified SQL Server technician.
To enable the server to determine the maximum degree of parallelism, set this option to 0, the default value. Setting maximum degree of parallelism to 0 allows SQL Server to use all the available processors up to 64 processors. To suppress parallel plan generation, set max degree of parallelism to 1. Set the value to a number from 1 to 32,767 to specify the maximum number of processor cores that can be used by a single query execution. If a value greater than the number of available processors is specified, the actual number of available processors is used. If the computer has only one processor, the max degree of parallelism value is ignored.
**You can override the max degree of parallelism value in queries by specifying the MAXDOP query hint in the query statement**.

Index operations that create or rebuild an index, or that drop a clustered index, can be resource intensive. You can override the max degree of parallelism value for index operations by specifying the MAXDOP index option in the index statement. 
The MAXDOP value is applied to the statement at execution time and is not stored in the index metadata.

In addition to queries and index operations, this option also controls the parallelism of DBCC CHECKTABLE, DBCC CHECKDB, and DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP. You can disable parallel execution plans for these statements by using trace flag 2528.

msdn source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189094(v=sql.110).aspx